# C#, MySQL - Retrieve row from table and populate variables in method then Add() method to List<>

Tags: c#, mysql

I am retrieving data from a database and trying to populate a List<>. That is my goal.

I am currently inserting the retrieved data into variables within a method and then trying to add the method to the List<>.

Here is my code:

```
public void Select()
    {
        var sprite = new Sprite();

        if (Game.player.inBattle)
        {
            //Open a connection
            databaseCon.Open(); //Works

            //Create Command
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand(BattleEngine.query, databaseCon); //Works

            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //Works

            try
            {

                //Read the data and store them in the list
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    //Inserts matching Row's first Column attribute into method variable

                    sprite.id = (dataReader.GetInt32(0));
                    //Inserts matching Row's second Column attribute into method variable

                    sprite.identifier = (dataReader.GetString(1)); 

                    Console.WriteLine(sprite.id + ": " + sprite.identifier); //Works. Variables are loaded with data

                    //Fails. Doesn't load the method into the list
                    Game.sprite.Add(new Sprite()); 
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex);

            }
            finally
            {
                if (dataReader != null)
                {
                    //close Data Reader
                    dataReader.Close();
                }

                if (databaseCon != null)
                {
                    //close Connection
                    databaseCon.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I then have a test `Console.WriteLine(Game.sprite[0]);` setup after this loops and it displays `Namespace.Sprite`

There are probably other ways of doing this but ultimately I would like to have the list populated with each record within a new method. By storing it in the List<> I can then pull specific information to be used later.

In theory I want to be able to do this;

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", Game.sprite[0].id);
```

I have seen this done before but I cannot seem to replicate it.

ADDITION:

```
public class Game
{
    public static Player player;
    public static List<Character> sprite;
    GameScreens mainMenu = new GameScreens();
    GameScreens titleScreen = new GameScreens();

    public Game()
    {
        Console.SetWindowSize(100, 50);
        Console.BufferHeight = 50;
        Console.BufferWidth = 100;

        titleScreen.TitleScreen();

        player = new Player();
        sprite = new List<Character>();
        Player.Initialize(player);

        GameLoop();
    }

    void GameLoop() //Our game loop.
    {
        mainMenu.MainMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the `Game.sprite` list created/instantiated?

Comment: At the start of my main loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`Game.sprite.Add(sprite);`

Instead of:

`Game.sprite.Add(new Sprite());`

Your code adds an empty `Sprite` object - not the one you declared

Comment: I've also attempted this before and I seem to get the same outcome.

Comment: What error are you receiving? Can you post the code where you instantiate the Game.sprite list?

Comment: also, try moving `var sprite = new Sprite();` to the first line of your while loop

Comment: Thank you, trebuchet! Moving that line did it! Also instead of `Console.WriteLine(Game.sprite[0]);` I used `Console.WriteLine("{0}", Game.sprite[0].id);` and it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been tried in the declaration `Sprite sprite = new Sprite();` instead of `var sprite = new Sprite();` and then `sprite.Add(new Sprite());` instead of the failing line?

Comment: "Sprite sprite = new Sprite()" and "var sprite = new Sprite()" are the same command for the .NET compiler

Comment: Unfortunately I want to add the new Sprite() to my list and not back onto it itself in a new instance. I was able to get it working though. Thank you for your input.